# How to show the number of user points within the user who posted a comment?

Tags: users, userpoints

I use the [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module. Despite of my searches, I didn't find answer to this question:

> **In the user profile of a comment, how to show the number of user points?**

For example to show the number of points below the picture of the user who posted a comment.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints)

> - Services integration: allowing retrieving and updating points on your    site using web services.
> - Rules integration
> - Views integration
> - A block displaying the number of points a user has gained
> - A block displays the top users who earned points
> - A status message telling the user how many points were earned/lost    and their total points
> - A detailed point total report for each individual user
> - A point total report for all users

[Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2)

> - The module is aimed to provide a simple, but extensible solution    providing a similar end user interface like the core profile module
>     by default.
> - Multiple profile types may be created via the UI (e.g. a general    profile + a customer profile), whereas the module provides separated
>     permissions for those.
> - Optionally, profile forms are shown during user account registration.
> - Similar to the deprecated core profile module, fields may be    configured to be private - thus visible only to the profile owner and 
>     administrators.
> - By default the UI behaves similar to the deprecated core profile    module, thus showing each profile type in each own tab below
>     user//edit. Via the included "Profile pages" module profiles can
>     be viewed and edited at their own page and get their own menu link,
>     e.g. "My profile".
> - Thanks to the foundational entity API the module integrates well with    Rules as well as Features - thus profile types and the
>     associated    fields can be exported into feature modules. Once the
>     Entity tokens    module (part of the Entity API) is turned on, there
>     are also token    replacements available.
> - You may use Views and/or the Search API to provide listings or    searches for profiles

Comment: hi Adi, thanks for your answer. But i just want the number of points in user profile comment (as on stackexchange, the reputation of the users appears in comments). It isn't too much to install a module for that?

Comment: you can display it on node using profile 2 module

Comment: Sorry but I do not see how display it with profile2... Another solution? I would have to add a field in the display of comments, and there are no additional features with regard to what is proposed by default (for information I use drupal 7)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to what is done in the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module (which comes with the `Answers Userpoints` sub-module that integrates with the [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module). The newest 7.x-4.0 version of [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) also comes with the (new) `Answers Theme` sub-module, which you can see at work in this [example question](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/50). Note the "***points***" that are shown below each author (user) to the left of a question or answer, which is similar to the "*user profile of a comment*" in your question.

These points are shown via what you can see in [this template file](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/answers/tree/answers_theme/templates/node--answers_question.tpl.php?h=7.x-4.x#n115) (used for nodes of type "Question"), the [template used for nodes of type "Answer"](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/answers/tree/answers_theme/templates/node--answers_answer.tpl.php?h=7.x-4.x#n116) is similar. Both templates are part of the `Answers Theme` sub-module. More specifically both templates have a line that looks like so:

```
<?php print userpoints_get_current_points($node->uid); print ' ' . t('points'); ?>
```

So to complete the answer to your question, this is how you can get it to work:

- Use a template related to the comments where you want to show the user points.
- Add a line similar to the code above, using `userpoints_get_current_points` and replace `$node->uid` in it by the user id of the user who posted the comment.
- Refer to the [documentation about userpoints_get_current_points](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/userpoints/userpoints-7.x-1.x!userpoints.module/function/userpoints_get_current_points/7-1) if you need more details.

<sub><sup>Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers)</sup></sub>.